# validate textbox & run another function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have textboxes & button on button click I am trying to open lightbox popup which is working. Problem is First it needs to check for validation If validation is true then only it should run popup function. But it's not happening. If textbox is empty then it shows alert but if I click ok On alert box then it immediately opens popup box. Following is my code

JS

```
function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById("txtSource").value == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Pick up location");
  } else if (document.getElementById("txtDestination").value == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Drop off location");
  } else if (document.getElementById("selectVehicle").value == "Select Vehicle")
    alert("Please Select Vehcile.")
    return true;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hidePopup").click(function() {
    $('.booking-popup').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });

  $("#openPopup").click(function() {
    $('.booking-popup').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });
});
```

Page Code

```
<asp:TextBox name="fname" ID="txtSource" onchange="GetRoute()" onblur="GetRoute()" runat="server" CssClass="inners" placeholder="From Area"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDestination" onchange="GetRoute()" onblur="GetRoute()" runat="server" CssClass="inners" placeholder="To Area"></asp:TextBox>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<asp:DropDownList ID="selectVehicle" onchange="GetRoute();" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" CssClass="inners">
  <asp:listitem Value="SelectVehicle" Selected>-- Select Vehicle --</asp:listitem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="20">Tata Ace</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="25">Bolero Pick Up</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:listitem Value="30">Tata 407</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem Value="35">14 Feet</asp:listitem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<asp:Button ID="openPopup" OnClientClick="validate(); GetRoute();" runat="server" CssClass="book" Text="GET QUICK QUOTE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return `false` in invalid and add `if` valid to `$("#openPopup").click(function () {`:-

```
function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById("txtSource").value == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Pick up location");
    return false;
  } else if (document.getElementById("txtDestination").value == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Drop off location");
    return false;
  } else if (document.getElementById("selectVehicle").value == "Select Vehicle") {
    alert("Please Select Vehcile.")
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}


 $("#openPopup").click(function () {
     if(validate())
       $('.booking-popup').css('visibility', 'visible');
 });
```

Comment: if everything is valid, then `true` will be returned and `$('.booking-popup').css('visibility', 'visible');` would get called. if not then show your markup too.

Comment: if validation gets true then nothing gets called on button click.

Comment: so it does a post back? do you ever want that button to do that? if not the add `return false` here : `OnClientClick="validate(); GetRoute(); return false;"`

Comment: Not working.. See this fiddle I tried with your code ..  https://jsfiddle.net/1zrpmmzu/7/

Comment: that fiddle is not working for a few reasons. 1 no select box, 2 no jQuery added, 3 css `visibility` for `#openPopup` instead of `.booking-popup`. try this updated versions:- https://jsfiddle.net/1zrpmmzu/8/

Answer (score 0):

Your button:

```
<asp:Button ID="openPopup" OnClientClick="return validate();" runat="server" CssClass="book" Text="GET QUICK QUOTE" />
```

Your JS:

```
function validate() {
            var result = 1;
            if (document.getElementById("txtSource").value == "") {
                result = 0;
                alert("Please Enter Pick up location");
            } 
            else if (document.getElementById("txtDestination").value == ""){
                result = 0;
                alert("Please Enter Drop off location");
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("selectVehicle").value == "Select Vehicle"){
                result = 0;
                alert("Please Select Vehcile.") 
            }
            if (result == 1){
                GetRoute();
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

I did in this way, because it is easier to understand by this example.

Comment: Where is lightbox popup i.e. #openpopup & #hidePopup? GetRoute(); is not my problem.

Comment: @StupidRomeo I just changed your *validate* function

Comment: @StupidRomeo if *GetRoute* is not your problem, you don't need such a big code

Comment: function validate() {
            if (document.getElementById("txtSource").value == "") {
                alert("Please Enter Pick up location"); return false;
            } 
            else if (document.getElementById("txtDestination").value == ""){
                alert("Please Enter Drop off location"); return false;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("selectVehicle").value == "Select Vehicle"){
                alert("Please Select Vehcile."); return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#openPopup").click(function () {
           if (document.getElementById("txtSource").value == "") {
               alert("Please Enter Pick up location");
               return false;
           } else if (document.getElementById("txtDestination").value == "") {
               alert("Please Enter Drop off location");
               return false;
           } else if (document.getElementById("selectVehicle").value == "Select Vehicle") {
               alert("Please Select Vehcile.")
               return false;
           }
           else {
               $('.booking-popup').css('visibility', 'visible');
           }
       });
```